# Selecting the pairs of numbers in a vector which difference is equal to a predetermined value

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector of numbers from which I would like to select the pairs that are 2 units apart. So if I have the vector `p` defined as follows:

```
p<-c(2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47)
```

I would like to select the following pairs:

```
3,5; 5,7; 11,13; 17,19; 29,31; 41,43
```

I tried unsuccessfully to select at least these numbers in a vector

```
j<-NULL
for(i in seq(p)) if (p[i+1]-p[i]==2) j<-c(j,i,i+1)
```

But it does not give the desired output. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better way than this, but here is an idea with `expand.grid`,

```
df <- expand.grid(p, p)
unname(apply(df[df[,1]-df[,2] == -2,], 1,paste, collapse = ','))
#[1] "3,5"   "5,7"   "11,13" "17,19" "29,31" "41,43"
```

If you want a data frame then simply,

```
df[df[,1]-df[,2] == 2,]
#    Var1 Var2
#18     5    3
#34     7    5
#66    13   11
#98    19   17
#146   31   29
#194   43   41
```

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why my code does not select the numbers properly?

Comment: The problem with your code is that you are using the index `i` rather than `p[i]`. Try `for(i in seq(p))  if (p[i+1]-p[i]==2) j<-c(j,p[i],p[i+1])`.

Comment: @David_B Thanks for your suggestion. However, it gives me the error 'missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed'

Comment: In spite of this the vector contains the needed values. Thanks.

Comment: The error is because you've asked R to loop over a sequence from 1 to 15, with 15 being the length of `p`, but your `if` statement includes a reference to `p[i + 1]`, which on the last iteration of the loop will be `p[16]`, which doesn't exist. But by then the loop has done the job you want.  If you want to prevent the error, just change the loop to `for(i in 1:14)`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution using base R functions:

```
dif=which(abs(diff(p))==2)
sapply(dif, function(x) c(p[x],p[x+1]))

   # [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    3    5   11   17   29   41
# [2,]    5    7   13   19   31   43
```

By changing `2` to any other value, you can manage to get the result of any desired unit from which the vector's elements are apart.

`abs` is used to take care of the cases in which vector's elements are not ordered.

**BENCHMARK (small scale)**

```
p<-c(2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47) # length(p)=15
library(dplyr)
library(data.table) 
library(microbenchmark)
func_Sotos <- function(p){df <- expand.grid(p, p);df[df[,1]-df[,2] == 2,];}
func_m0h3n <- function(p){dif=which(abs(diff(p))==2);sapply(dif, function(x) c(p[x],p[x+1]));}
func_David_B <- function(p){data.frame(p) %>% mutate(lagp = lag(p))  %>% filter(p - lagp == 2)}
func_akrun1 <- function(p){setDT(list(p=p))[, p1 := shift(p)][p-p1 ==2];}
func_akrun2 <- function(p){unique(CJ(p=p, p1=p)[abs(p-p1)==2][.(p=pmin(p,p1), p1=pmax(p, p1))]);}
func_RHertel1 <- function(p){d2_mat <- which(as.matrix(dist(p))==2, arr.ind=TRUE);unique(t(apply(cbind(p[d2_mat[,1]],p[d2_mat[,2]]),1,sort)));}
func_RHertel2 <- function(p){m2 <- t(combn(sort(p),2));m2[abs(m2[,1] - m2[,2]) == 2,];}
func_RHertel3 <- function(p){d2 <- as.matrix(dist(p));d2[lower.tri(d2)] <- 0;idx <- which(d2 == 2, arr.ind=TRUE);cbind(p[idx[,1]], p[idx[,2]]);}
func_Tomas.H <- function(p) {a<-which(p-lag(p)==2);b<-a-1;df<-data.frame(pair1=p[b],pair2=p[a]);df;}
func_Arun.kumar.mahesh <- function(p) {
j<-c()
    for(i in 1:length(p)){
      if(sum(p[i]-p[i+1],na.rm=T)==-2){
        j[i] <- paste(p[i],p[i+1],sep=",")
      }
    }
    j <- j[!is.na(j)]
}
microbenchmark(func_Sotos(p), func_m0h3n(p), func_David_B(p), func_akrun1(p), func_akrun2(p), func_RHertel1(p), func_RHertel2(p), func_RHertel3(p), func_Tomas.H(p), func_Arun.kumar.mahesh(p))

Unit: microseconds
                      expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
             func_Sotos(p)  403.770  455.9520  470.6952  469.6390  485.4640  594.961   100
             func_m0h3n(p)   72.713   92.8155  125.7504   98.8040  104.7920 2622.790   100
           func_David_B(p) 1986.340 2148.2335 2260.4203 2207.0450 2292.1615 5547.553   100
            func_akrun1(p) 1321.233 1404.2110 1472.6807 1464.3060 1504.7255 1872.566   100
            func_akrun2(p) 2524.414 2623.2185 2777.9167 2700.2080 2816.5485 5595.885   100
          func_RHertel1(p) 1160.838 1230.5560 1349.9502 1267.7680 1328.7185 4133.504   100
          func_RHertel2(p)  249.362  281.2270  298.3233  296.1975  308.3880  562.027   100
          func_RHertel3(p)  159.968  182.8515  204.4812  203.1675  223.6985  304.538   100
           func_Tomas.H(p)  275.453  316.0865  337.7593  334.6925  350.7320  646.716   100
 func_Arun.kumar.mahesh(p)  123.184  142.2175  174.5620  148.4200  158.0435 2579.163   100
```

**BENCHMARK (medium scale)**

```
set.seed(100)
p=sample(1000) # length(p)=1000

microbenchmark(func_Sotos(p), func_m0h3n(p), func_David_B(p), func_akrun1(p), func_akrun2(p), func_RHertel1(p), func_RHertel2(p), func_RHertel3(p), func_Tomas.H(p), func_Arun.kumar.mahesh(p))
Unit: microseconds
                      expr        min          lq         mean      median          uq        max neval
             func_Sotos(p)  30711.250  35060.8410  53640.60456  64290.0265  69224.6310  98474.248   100
             func_m0h3n(p)     41.465     68.9580     88.75608     83.5305    102.1600    196.808   100
           func_David_B(p)    854.835   1067.1160   1220.68932   1150.1960   1261.5205   3934.944   100
            func_akrun1(p)    524.319    748.9200    830.18763    811.5670    896.2995   1549.519   100
            func_akrun2(p)  12986.877  17372.2235  34010.07038  21836.1435  52173.1590  58796.699   100
          func_RHertel1(p)  76813.429 107942.6315 112380.30785 115049.1765 119579.6505 163399.316   100
          func_RHertel2(p) 280275.495 297188.4505 307531.70976 304330.0005 314177.5760 360689.445   100
          func_RHertel3(p)  45957.354  85348.1045 103999.44879 113351.6765 118847.8575 170738.875   100
           func_Tomas.H(p)    154.742    212.4325    263.66812    260.8075    295.0610    536.037   100
 func_Arun.kumar.mahesh(p)    972.619   1072.5250   1192.35206   1152.4500   1238.9850   2483.979   100
```

Comment: After computing "dif", an alternative is `cbind(p[dif], p[dif + 1])`

Comment: Does it work, e.g.,  with `p<-c(7,2,37,3,31,47,13,43,23,17,5,41,29,19,11)`?

Comment: You may also want to check the case `p<-c(2,3,4,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47)`. Just by inserting a `4` in the ordered vector, the first pair of the previous output gets lost.

Comment: I think you did not get the question rightly. Given your `p` vector, the result is perfectly right. The first pair does no longer appear since in your case, the first pair that is `2` unit apart would be `5` and `7`! Its very simple!

Answer (score 2):

Hi if desired outcome is data frame then try this

```
p<-c(2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47)

a<-which(p-lag(p)==2)
b<-a-1

df<-data.frame(pair1=p[b],
               pair2=p[a])
```

If you want back a vector then this should work

```
res<-NULL
for (i in a){

    res<-c(res,p[i-1],p[i])
}
```

Comment: It does not work for me as the df is empty. I checked p-lag(p) and it gives a vector of 0s

Comment: Perhaps I am doing something wrong as I get res to be NULL. Have you tried your solution? I am copying your answer, but it does not work.

Comment: I tried and it worked basically problem is that you get 0 when you did p-lag(p). This should make differences between first element of p and second element of p, then difference between second element of p and third element. But for you it does not work

Comment: I do not understand what was the problem in the first instance. Now p-lag(p) gives the right output. Thanks.

Comment: Just use `diff` instead of `lag`. It's not working for me either (get an empty data.frame).

Comment: `b <- which(c(p[-1], NA) - p ==2)`

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using `dplyr`, which will return the pairs in a data frame:

```
> library(dplyr)
> data.frame(p) %>% mutate(lagp = lag(p))  %>% filter(p - lagp == 2)
   p lagp
1  5    3
2  7    5
3 13   11
4 19   17
5 31   29
6 43   41
```

Comment: This is even more handy than the answer I approved first. Thanks.

Comment: This solution, too, assumes that the values in `p` are ordered.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another using `data.table`

```
library(data.table) 
setDT(list(p=p))[, p1 := shift(p)][p-p1 ==2]
#    p p1
#1:  5  3
#2:  7  5
#3: 13 11
#4: 19 17
#5: 31 29
#6: 43 41
```

If the `vector` p is not ordered, `order` it before doing the operation.

```
setDT(list(p=p))[order(p)][, p1 := shift(p)][p-p1==2]
```

#### Update

Using the new vector provided by @RHertel

```
p <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47)
unique(CJ(p=p, p1=p)[abs(p-p1)==2][.(p=pmin(p,p1), p1=pmax(p, p1))])
#    p p1
#1:  2  4
#2:  3  5
#3:  5  7
#4: 11 13
#5: 17 19
#6: 29 31
#7: 41 43
```

Answer (score 2):

Kind of hacky, but here's another way.

```
d2_mat <- which(as.matrix(dist(p))==2, arr.ind=TRUE)
unique(t(apply(cbind(p[d2_mat[,1]],p[d2_mat[,2]]),1,sort)))
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    3    5
#[2,]    5    7
#[3,]   11   13
#[4,]   17   19
#[5,]   29   31
#[6,]   41   43
```

In contrast to some of the other answers, this does not require any specific order of the numbers in the vector `p`.

---

A vectorized version of the same could be:

```
d2 <- as.matrix(dist(p))
d2[lower.tri(d2)] <- 0
idx <- which(d2 == 2, arr.ind=TRUE)
cbind(p[idx[,1]], p[idx[,2]])
```

In the last line, instead of `cbind()`, one could also use `paste()`, depending on the desired output:

```
paste(p[idx[,1]], p[idx[,2]], sep=",")
#[1] "3,5"   "5,7"   "11,13" "17,19" "29,31" "41,43"
```

---

The following variant is simpler and probably (much) faster than my previous suggestions.

```
m2 <- t(combn(sort(p),2))
m2[abs(m2[,1] - m2[,2]) == 2,]
```

This version, too, finds all pairs of values that are 2 units apart within any integer vector.

Here's an example:

```
p <- c(13, 19, 43, 29, 47, 17, 7, 37, 2, 41, 3, 4, 31, 11, 5, 23)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2    4
#[2,]    3    5
#[3,]    5    7
#[4,]   11   13
#[5,]   17   19
#[6,]   29   31
#[7,]   41   43
```

The output can be modified, if desired, by using:

```
m2 <- t(combn(sort(p), 2))
m2 <- m2[abs(m2[,1] - m2[,2]) == 2,]
paste(m2[,1], m2[,2], sep=",")
#[1] "2,4"   "3,5"   "5,7"   "11,13" "17,19" "29,31" "41,43"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Use length function instead of seq to get desired output

    j<-c()
    for(i in 1:length(p)){
      if(sum(p[i]-p[i+1],na.rm=T)==-2){
        j[i] <- paste(p[i],p[i+1],sep=",")
      }
    }
    j <- j[!is.na(j)]
    print(j)
    [1] "3,5"   "5,7"   "11,13" "17,19" "29,31" "41,43"
```

Comment: In 1:seq(p) ; only the first element will be used